# C# Read .txt file, store its data and edit the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, readfile, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to do something pretty simple. I am making a Windows Form Application, it's a simple 'Student grade calculator' essentially. I have the form working, it can read the file and show its data in a text box. However, I need to store each line's columns in their own fields.

You can see below an example of a file it should read/edit/save.

[image]

This is what I currently have that I use to read in a file:

```
      private void LoadFile()
    {
        string lineFromFile;

        fileContentTextBox.Clear();

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    lineFromFile = reader.ReadLine();

                    fileContentTextBox.AppendText(lineFromFile);

                    fileContentTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
```

So, how would I be able to store its data in fields such as:

- moduleCode1 "SOFT152"
- examWeighting1 "0.3"
- courseworkeMark1 "65"
- etc..

I know that you have to use something like this, but I'm not sure how to use it in this situation where I need to store the file's data in many individual fields?

```
    lines[i].Split(',')
```

The output in the form would look something like this in the end:

[image]

If there is a better way of doing this, like taking each line into a string and then separating it or something please let me know.

Comment: Using `Split(',')` would indeed split that string into multiple strings where the comma separates those strings.  The result would be an array of strings.  Did you try it?

Comment: I did try it, and I think it worked since it didn't give me any errors, however I don't know how to use that array. This is the code I tried:
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName); 
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++) 
        { 
        var fields = lines[i].Split(',');
        }

Comment: Is this homework? You should tag it as homework if this is so. You might get some more people to help, in that case.

Comment: Thanks, will do so :)

Comment: What about using a DataGridView

Comment: Wouldn't that just show file content in the form? I need to be able to use the file data in order to calculate the overall grade etc, that is why I would like to store it

Comment: @Dr4ken: In that example you now have, within your loop, a variable called `fields`.  That variable is an array of strings, and it contains all of the individual string values from that line of text.  From there, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Model and parse your data as @pookie described in his answer. From there you could bind the list to a DataGridView for display and still use the list as a data source for any calculations you require.

Comment: @Dr4ken Updated my answer with a code example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't describe with code as I'm on my phone, but I would do something like this:

Create a new class, call it student if you want. Inside student, create the properties you require (eg mark, weighing).

In your main program, creating a new list of student.

In your while loop, where you read the line, create a new student. Then, split the line into your string array. Access the string array by index, grab your properties and assign the value to the student properties.

Finally, add the created student to the student list.

**UPDATE with some code**

Okay, so let's imagine that you were creating an address book for students.

You would have a `Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your main program, you want to create a list to store your students:

```
var students = new List<Student>();
```

Finally, you want to read the file, create your student and add him/her to the list:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
     var student = new Student();
     ineFromFile = reader.ReadLine();
     var arrayOfProperties = ineFromFile.Split();
     student.Name = arrayOfProperties[0]; #Make sure you know the indices, or you will have to create a custom parser ;)
     student.Age = (int)arrayOfProperties[1]; #Remember to convert from string.
     students.Add(student); # add your student!
}
```

Comment: I will try this, I've made a class with all the properties, and I will do the rest as you have described. I will let you know how it goes, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey, I've managed to do 'something'. Which is different to what you said, purely because I kept failing and the way I got it to work was the first that worked out of many things I have tried. I'm not sure how to fully show through comments, so I've uploaded it here: https://paste.ofcode.org/UgzbFJCAb8Sgm7yKFeqUTc 
This is what it looks like when it's ran and file is loaded: 
https://i.gyazo.com/836cc6a78e4c043777237049248e26e6.png
The DataGridView is just there temporarily just so I can see that the file content easier.

Comment: If you could show me an example of your way (which is definitely 100x better than my mess), then I could maybe try to do implement it into mine  or if you know what can be changed in my version. There are other things that I will need to do later, but first I want to be able to read the file, show its content accordingly, and be able to use some variables to calculate the overall mark etc. Thanks for the help, it did clear up a few things I misunderstood :)

Comment: Where would I put the "var students = new List<Student>();"? since it's the windows form and there is no 'main program'? Or am I missing something and there is a main program. I've tried putting that code into some places, but I always get the "the name 'modules' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: nvm, I added it here: 
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    var modules = new List<Module>();
and it seems to work now.

Comment: @Dr4ken, great! Let me know if there are any more issues. If you have any other questions, feel free to create another thread and let me know.

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the help, everything turned out better than expected. Tomorrow I will need to do some extra things. If I need help (I definitely will xd), I'll let you know. Thanks for all the help!